# Postgis - Spatial relationships in metres

Tags: postgis, srid, spatial-query

I'm trying to perform some spatial relationship analysis using Postgis functions like `st_dwithin` and `st_dfullywithin`. I searched and found that for any SRID, using the `geography` type gives the results in metres which works well for `st_dwithin`. However, the `st_dfullywithin` the arguments need to be of type `geometry` so this approach does not work.

My base SRID is 4283 and I've tried transforming the SRID of the geometry objects to SRID 3577 which still does not work.

As a test, I tried to measure the distance between two points using different SRID and the geometry and geography types. 
I believe the units of 3577 is in metres, but when I run the test to get the distance between two points using SRID 3577 it returns the results in degrees, but changing the type to geography returns metres.

I thought changing the SRID to one with metres should return metres? If not, how can you work in metres?

EDIT: The query to get the distance which gives the result in degrees is,

```
select st_distance(st_geomfromtext('POINT(150.9319747 -33.8482439)', 3557), st_geomfromtext('POINT(151.9319747 -34.8482439)', 3557))
```

If I use the same SRID, I have to use the following query to get the result in metres

```
select st_distance(st_geomfromtext('POINT(150.9319747 -33.8482439)', 3557)::geography, st_geomfromtext('POINT(151.9319747 -34.8482439)', 3557)::geography)
```

My ultimate aim is to fine `geom`s that are within a given radius of a point,

```
select 
*
from table_1 a
where ST_DWithin(st_transform(a.geom, 3557), st_transform(st_geomfromtext('POINT(150.9319747 -33.8482439)', 4283),3557), 50000);
```

Inspite of using the different SRIDs, the relationship still considers degrees and not meters.

Comment: Show the query please.

Answer (score 4):

Your query:

```
select st_distance(st_geomfromtext('POINT(150.9319747 -33.8482439)', 3557), st_geomfromtext('POINT(151.9319747 -34.8482439)', 3557))
```

is not transforming the geometry. You are just telling PostGIS that your coordinates are in SRID 3557.

If you want to transform the geometry, you need:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(150.9319747 -33.8482439)', 4326),3557), ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(151.9319747 -34.8482439)', 4326), 3557))
```

However, your points are out of bounds for projection 3557. Try 3857 (Web Mercator), or another projection that is better suited for your area of interest.